# Replacing a component in an Eagle board that has already been routed?

Tags: eaglecad

I'm pretty new to eagle so there might be a better way to do this..

There's an error in one of the parts I'm using.  It has one of the connections from the schematic to the board going to the wrong I/O pin.  The problem is I've already routed the whole thing before I noticed it.

I changed the connection in the library part file but I think I need to update the part in my board somehow?  It's still showing up with the old connection.  I've tried deleting the part and adding a new one in but I loose all of the routing that I've done.  What's the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eagle has a command for updating components from their libraries.

```
update;
```

(will update all components from their respective libraries).

If you would rather only update components from a specific library, do as follows:

```
update mylibrary;
```

This way you'll only have to re-route the pins that have the wrong connection.